# Load SQLite database from remote SQL Server?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, in-memory

I'm using SQLite ADO.NET in my project so that I can unit test using an in-memory database.  I want a copy of my real database but it is across the server.  From what I've read, it looks like I have to specify ":memory" for the data source for the SQLite connection string.  My problem is that I don't even know if it's possible to load a remote database into memory that is not a SQLite database, or how to do it?  Any thoughts on how this could be done?  It's not a large db--maybe 5 megs at most.  Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, figured out it doesn't matter--I can't use SQLite with ADO.NET because my queries are all T-SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need an in-memory database, you can use [SQL Server Express](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Express) on your PC, or a unit-testing VM.

You could overwrite the database file each time you run the test.